# About "git bash" and "VS code"

Tags: visual-studio-code, git-bash

I am new to Web Development and wish your help, please.

I used "git bash" to create a folder named: "class-demo" and then created inside that folder a file named "demos.py". Now I want to open that file using VS Code application, but I can't because I don't know how to specify the location of the folder or the file I have just created by "git bash"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can, in your git bash session where you just have created your file type `explorer .` or `cmd`.

In both case, you will see the Windows path (`C:\...`) or your current folder.

You can use that path to open it in VSCode.